# TFS Build: Run a Powershell script as administrator

Tags: powershell, tfs, permissions, tfsbuild, uac

I created a build definition for our nightly build server.
After building the project (a windows service), I need to execute a Powershell script to install and start the service. So I added a build step to run the specific Powershell script. Then I installed a TFS Build Agent & Visual Studio at the (soon to be) nightly build server.
After running the build script I got an 'exit code 5' which seems to be related to missing administratior permissions.
If I start the script as admin on the server manually, it works fine.
The user, which is used by the agent, already got admin permissions.

Is there a way to execute the powershell script on the build server with a build agent / build definition with admin permissions?

Comment: You can't bypass the UAC prompt, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Our admins configured the server to disable UAC, so this should not be the problem

Comment: This is unfortunate. Disabling UAC is definitely not recommended.

Comment: Is there another way to get along with UAC when executing PowerShell scripts (that require admin permissions) in TFS build definitions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to make sure your build service account (which can be a local account, a domain account, or Local Service in a workgroup) also got admin permission.

Comment: The user configured for the build agent already got full admin permissions, yet i still get error code 5 problems when executing the powershell script

Comment: Okay, problem solved... The machine had to be restartet after the permission change (i should have known it better after 20 years as a Windows user)